# Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code 1) error

Tags: c++, xcode, pointers

When I run this short program, I generate the error "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code 1)". Can anyone help me determine the cause of the problem?

```
//populates matrix with rand nums
void popMat(int x[][4096]){
for(int i = 0; i < 4096; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < 4096; j++){
        x[i][j] = rand() % 100;
    }
}
return;
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {

int mat1 [4096][4096];
int mat2 [4096][4096];

popMat(mat1);
popMat(mat2);

for(int i = 0; i < 4096; i++){
    for(int h = 0; h < 4096; h++){
        printf("%d, %d\n", i, h);
    }

}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: What does the debugger tell you? Line the error occurs, stack trace, stack pointer, etc? That should help you spot the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming 4 bytes integer, `int mat1 [4096][4096];` requires 64MB of memory. Two such arrays require 128 MB of memories. On most systems stack memory, where local variables are created, is not capable of storing such large memory and you are getting a stack overflow.

One easy solution is to move the array is global scope(using global is not much recommended). Another solution is to allocate these arrays dynamically with `malloc` or `new`. Another solution is to use `std::vector` instead of statically allocated C arrays.

PS:

- Do not forget to free memory if you decide to allocate them dynamically.
- Even after you fix this issue you will see that `rand()` is always generating same values as `srand()` is not called.